# How to compare sub string in if controller of jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a value  ${Group} = ABC. I just want "If controller" return true if ${Group} == A.
I have tried with ${__javaScript("${group}".contains=="A")} but it does not work.
Please help me for this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript there is no "contains()" method, I think that you need to use [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) instead as

```
"${group}".indexOf("A") > -1
```

Remember that variable names are **case sensitive** as well as "A" character so `${Group}` and `${group}` are totally **different** variables.

See [How to use JMeter's 'IF' Controller and get Pie.](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) guide for more details and clues.